# mount point - permission denied

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

I created a fuse mountpoint. After mounting, the file permissions are all screwed up and it says I cannot ls or cd. `Permission denied`.

The file permissions look like this:

> d????????? ? ? ? ? ? temp

and when i list the mounted devices I get:
/dev/fuse on /temp type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev)

I used mono-fuse. I just created a new folder with permissions 777 and then did a mount. After unmounting I can do all operations, but when I mount, I get such error.

I used
HelloFS.exe that comes along with mono fuse for testing.

Can someone shed some light on this weird behavior and what mistake i have done.

Comment: This is not a programming related question, and belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Sorry im new to this forum. Thanks! I will post it in super user. Thanks !!

Comment: This *is* a programming question, the OP is trying to write a FUSE filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect there is an incompatiblity with the userspace fuse library you're using and the kernel fuse version. This results in the kernel not understanding responses and it returning and EIO for everything (including the stat calls that "ls" does).

You should try increasing the debug level. As it's a Mono / CLR application, ensure that the libraries are of an appropriate version for your kernel; you may not need to recompile it.

You should also note that when you mount a directory, the mount-point's original permissions are ignore (and hence need not be 0777) ; the root directory of the new filesystem takes its place.

(You should probably not mount such a filesystem in /temp either; it is an example not for temp files)

Comment: /temp isn't a special mount point (at least in any UNIX or Linux system I've ever used). /tmp is.